# What is the mathematical notation of in the range of a value higher than

Tags: notation

I have the following data:

```
ε     Measure_X
0     5.6
0.02  2.36
0.1   6.02
0.8   1.69
1.56  6.66
1.69  0
```

I am trying to find the proper notation to say that `This is the reason why not including values that are higher than 1.56 up to 5`. The number 5 means something to me. Basically, we are not interested in showing the values that result in `Measure_X` of zero.

Can I something like `This is the reason why not including values of ε ∈ [>1.56 , 5]`? If this is not correct, how to fix that?

Comment: $\varepsilon\in[1.56,5]$ means $1.56\le\varepsilon\le5$; that is using [interval notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals)

Answer (score 1):

One might simply say "Measure_x is zero on the interval $(1.56,5]$, so we have not shown it on this table."

Notice we use "$($" next to the $1.56$, which indicates that we do **not** exclude $1.56$ itself.